# If you give me, you may be forsaken

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

I can be given and taken. 
When given, the giver is often forsaken. 
I come in a garden variety and more, 
but cannot be bought at your typical store.

When you can take me, you may well rejoice, 
or you may have me without a choice. 
If you don't have me, you may be a wall 
if you're not found when superiors call.

**What am I?**

Hint:

> A Sabbath, a long one, may well be me, 
>  Or I might for your new motherhood be. 
>  If you you are ill, I will come to your aid, 
>  But those who take me won't always get paid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial answer**

You are

> leave

*I can be given and taken.
When given, the giver is often forsaken.*

> not sure...

*I come in a garden variety and more,
but cannot be bought at your typical store.*

> based on a comment from OP I believe this refers to [Garden leave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_leave)

*When you can take me, you may well rejoice,*

> taking leave can be for recreation

*or you may have me without a choice.*

> unpaid leave, forced time off

*If you don't have me, you may be a wall
if you're not found when superiors call.*

> "a wall" sounds like AWOL (absent without leave), which is when your superiors in the military can't find you.

**the hints**

*A Sabbath, a long one, may well be me,*

> a sabbatical is a long leave

*Or I might for your new motherhood be.*

> maternity leave

*If you you are ill, I will come to your aid,*

> sick day

*But those who take me won't always get paid!*

> not all days off are paid!

Comment: Nice! I had something else in mind for "garden," though.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon ah, thank you. Any hint on the first line?

Comment: It's a different (but related) sense of the word.

Comment: Line 1- to/from employer

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, not a native speaker - but I have to try it anyway (or maybe just because of that)... ;)

> a break ?

Comment: Good attempt (+1), but it's not the answer, and I think there are some clues that don't fit.

Comment: Not sure what your reasoning was but your answer was very close! +1

Answer (score -1):

> Retirement

Is my answer correct?

Comment: This does seem to fit many of the clues, and your on the right track, but this isn't it.

Comment: Hi 陆小凤 welcome to Puzzle.SE! In the future please include justification/explanation for your answer. If you're interested in learning more and getting your first badge, checkout the tour at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour